# USB modeswitch target mode, endpoint not found error

Tags: python, usb, modem, usb-modeswitch

So I did a script on linux, and now I am try to run it on my banana pi (with bananian) and I got some problems. I use usb modeswitch to change the mode of my modem. But now my modem goes directly in target mode, and then I can not change it anymore. When I do an lsusb I get:

> Bus 001 Device 026: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.

before I used to have:

> Bus 001 Device 026: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.

Therefore I was doing:

```
   usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'"
```

in the terminal or in my python script and every thing worked well.
Now I try something like:

`usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14dc -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000`'

And I get this message int the terminal:

> Looking for default devices ...    found matching product ID    adding
>   device  Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
>   Accessing device 026 on bus 001 ... Getting the current device
>   configuration ...  OK, got current device configuration (1) Using
>   first interface: 0x00 Error: message endpoint not given or found.
>   Aborting

I tried a lot of different Message that I found on the internet. But I don't really get how this usb modeswitch works. Can someone explain what is wrong in my method?

Comment: I found an answer here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/489936/huawei-e3531-view-signal-strength

thank you